# Waiting for result in promise chain consisting of .fetch(), .all() and .()then

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I'm trying to write a Promise Chain. This is abstractly speaking what I want to do:

1. `fetch()` a record from an API. (My Item)
2. `then()` Search in this record for more API links. (Here I find the links to the media that belong to the item. Each item can have any number of media).
3. `all()` Execute an API call for each of these links with `.fetch()`
4. `then()` if all previous promises are fulfilled, execute the render
   function that depends on this data.

This is the code I have created for this so far.

```
getItemWithAllMedia(request) {
    return fetch(request)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
      })
      .then((result) => {
        let media_links = Array.from(result["o:media"], (x) => x["@id"]);
        return media_links;
      })
      .then((media_links) => {
        return Promise.all(media_links.map((url) => fetch(url)));
      })
      .then((media_response) => {
        /// debugging results from promise.all
        console.log(media_response); // (2) [Response, Response]
        console.log(media_response[0]); // Response {type: "basic", url: "XXX", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
        console.log(media_response[0].json()); // Promise {<pending>}

        /// desired function: all responses to json and push to an array
        media_response.forEach((element) => {
          media_data.push(element.json());
        });

        /// show created array for debugging
        console.log(media_data);
        return media_data;
      })
```

As you can see from the comments, it doesn't work. I only got back the underfilled Promise. With which my loop of course does not work. I then tried to append `.then()`. Both inside `Promise.all()` and after the `.then()` in which I assumed it. But this has the same result. Unfortunately, I have not found a way how I can wait for the result. I thought then should go back a step and read about Promises in general. Is it possible that I have to do this with `await`/`async`? But then I have to write the complete function differently or? It would be great if someone knows if this can be done? Or should I restart with Await and Async?

**EDIT**
Spelling error in the variable and accordingly corrected the console output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that you have a spelling issue with `media_reponse`, you should really call  `.json()` on the response as soon as you have it. So do:

```
  // ....
  .then((media_links) => {
    return Promise.all(media_links.map((url) => fetch(url).then(response => response.json()));
  })
```

This will produce a promise that resolves to all the data.

Comment: oh man, i tried just that. Probably the spelling was the mistake. I'm sorry for your trouble.

Comment: Yes, but my point here is also that the way you managed the promises was not optimal, as your code *first* waits for all responses to be available, and only then starts to call `json()` on them.